# Any way to do same calculation for different types of variables just one function?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have some different types of variables, which need the same calculations. For example:

```cpp
int func(int a, int b) 
{
  return a+b;
}

QVector3D func(QVector3D a, QVector3D b) 
{
  return a+b;
}
```

The operations done in the two functions can be very complicated, but in fact, they do the same calculations just for different types of parameters and return different types of value.
Is there any way to write just one function for these different types of variables in c++ ?

Comment: Are you familiar templates? If not, they would be a good thing to google

Comment: Not familiar. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For what it's worth, `std::plus` is the solution to your concrete problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending on rtpax's comment, you can write a template function to perform the '+' operator with two arbitrary types (the same types or otherwise). The requirement is that the '+' operator must exist for the combination of types used.

```
template <typename T, typename K>
auto foo(T _a, K _b ) -> decltype(_a + _b) {
    return _a + _b;
}
```

The english version of the function signature is: A function foo, that takes two types, T and K, where the return type is the return type of the operation T + K.